# Making apprequest from Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, apprequests

Is it possible to do apprequest from Windows Phone 7. Now this all is working just fine on desktop browsers but on my WP7 browser (IE) it doesn't work. Now here is the HTML:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>My Great Canvas app</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
    FB.init({ 
       appId:'XXX',
       cookie:true, 
       status:true,
       xfbml:true
    });

    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests', 
        message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...',
        display: 'popup'
    });
</script>

</body>
```

When I open this on Windows Phone 7 I get this:

API Error Code: 3

API Error Description: Unknown method

Error Message: This method isn't supported for this display type

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Facebook bug. Unfortunately, there is no work around at this point. You can subscribe to the bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/291633774212504?browse=search_4f4320292bf967091684506